# Edit Magento 2.1.6 Cart Sidebar Links

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, sidebar

I need to change the Links to which those buttons in the cart sidebar redirect.

I can't find the file to edit them.
I have marked in a red box the buttoms to edit

My version of Magento is 2.1.6

[image: buttons]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the file app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml or
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml and related javascript files. Then you have a clear idea which one need to extend.

Comment: Yes, I found them, but the links and the button texts are not there. . .!

Comment: It comes from knockout js.